# vtk DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID format for cylinder

Tags: vtk, paraview

For my project I need to plot huge amount of data as connected network of spheres and cylinders as connectors. I'm now using Paraview to plot the data in vtk format. For spheres I used `UNSTRUCTURED_GRID` format:

```
vtk DataFile Version 2.0

Unstructured grid legacy vtk file with point scalar data 

ASCII

DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID

POINTS 3 double

7 16 9

16 16 21

25 34 36

POINT_DATA 3

SCALARS radii double

LOOKUP_TABLE default

5

10

13
```

which still needs `GLYTH` filter with appropriate scaling (will be done in Paraview).

Anybody knows what is the similar format for cylinders?

Answer (score 0):

The `Glyph` filter allows you to change the **Glyph Source** type to be a `Cylinder` instead of a `Sphere`.